# C long double in golang

Tags: c, go, long-double

I am porting an algorithm from C to Go. And I got a little bit confused. This is the C function:

```
void gauss_gen_cdf(uint64_t cdf[], long double sigma, int n)
{
    int i;
    long double s, d, e;

    //Calculations ...

    for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
       cdf[i] = s;
    }   
}
```

And in the for loop value "s" is assigned to element "x" the array cdf. How is this possible? As far as I know, a long double is a float64 (in the Go context). So I shouldn't be able to compile the C code because I am assigning an long double to an array which just contains uint64 elements. But the C code is working fine.

So can someone please explain why this is working?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:

The original C code of the function can be found here: https://github.com/mjosaarinen/hilabliss/blob/master/distribution.c#L22

Comment: Even in C your code is not meaningful and probably has some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So improve the C code to make it standard compliant.

Comment: Why not just use an existing implementation of a gaussian distribution in Go (such as [go-gaussian](https://github.com/chobie/go-gaussian/)) instead of porting C code again (and introducing your own bugs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment `cdf[i] = s` performs an implicit conversion to `uint64_t`.  It's hard to tell if this is intended without the calculations you omitted.

In practice, `long double` as a type has considerable variance across architectures.  Whether Go's `float64` is an appropriate replacement depends on the architecture you are porting from.  For example, on x86, `long double` is an 80-byte extended precision type, but [Windows systems are usually configured in such a way to compute results only with the 53-bit mantissa](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/830), which means that `float64` could still be equivalent for your purposes.

**EDIT** In this particular case, the values computed by the sources appear to be static and independent of the input.  I would just use `float64` on the Go side and see if the computed values are identical to those of the C version, when run on a x86 machine under real GNU/Linux (virtualization should be okay), to work around the Windows FPU issues.  The choice of x86 is just a guess because it is likely what the original author used.  I do not understand the underlying cryptography, so I can't say whether a difference in the computed values impact the security.  (Also note that the C code does not seem to properly seed its PRNG.)

Comment: I updated the question and added a link to the original source code. Thank you for the explanation regarding the different architectures.

Comment: Thanks, I had a brief look at the C sources and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> C long double in golang

The title suggests an interest in whether of not Go has an [extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) floating-point type similar to [`long double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) in C.

The answer is:

- Not as a primitive, see [Basic types](https://tour.golang.org/basics/11).
- But *arbitrary precision* is supported by the [math/big library](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/).

---

> Why this is working?

```
long double s = some_calculation();
uint64_t a = s;
```

It compiles because, unlike Go, C allows for certain implicit type conversions.  The *integer portion* of the floating-point value of `s` will be copied.  Presumably the `s` value has been scaled such that it can be interpreted as a [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) value where, based on the linked library source, [`0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`](https://github.com/mjosaarinen/hilabliss/blob/c098abf744e28a11d8d9dc422a1a0ace98f369fc/distribution.c#L40) (2^64-1) represents the value 1.0.  In order to make the most of such assignments, it may be worthwhile to have used an extended floating-point type with 64 precision bits.

If I had to guess, I would say that the (crypto-related) library is using fixed-point here because they want to ensure deterministic results, see: [How can floating point calculations be made deterministic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7365790/86967).  And since the extended-precision floating point is only being used for initializing a lookup table, using the (presumably slow) math/big library would likely perform perfectly fine in this context.