Scoped Enum Class, valid enumerator names
I am working on a some C++11 code that is developed in MS Visual Studio, but then later compiled with gcc for an ARM target.  In defining some view states, I create the following scoped enum
enum class viewState {
   off,
   min, 
   default,
   max
};

Which compiled and ran just fine in windows.  However, gcc didn't like it at all with an error that said, "expected identifier before 'default'"
For an easy fix, I changed 'default' to 'defaultView' which seems a little redundant to me, but isn't that big of a deal and it then compiled in gcc.
When I wrote it, I kind of wondered about using default, since it is a keyword for a switch statement and for explicitly-defaulted constructors, but it compiled and ran fine with MSVC.
I would think that inside of a scoped enum, it shouldn't really matter what the enumerator names are.
On the surface, it doesn't seem unreasonable to ensure that keywords aren't used for an enumerator name, but I feel like with a scoped enum, it is pretty easy to differentiate meaning.  Maybe this is one of those easy for humans, hard for computer issues.
Any thoughts?
If a keyword is defined to only be used in a switch-statement, is it actually illegal to use the keyword in a non-switch-statement?  MSVC seems to indicate no, and gcc does.  Is that part of a standard?
I changed 'default' to 'defaultView' which seems a little redundant to me, but isn't that big of a deal and it then compiled in gcc.

Funny, in the markup, it even highlights 'default' differently.

what is the question? "Any thoughts?" Isnt a specific question. Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/q/7365790/4117728 and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword ?

MSVC is weird. It stops accepting that if you add e.g. /std:c++latest.

You can't use names that are keywords in the language, anywhere.

I think this question would be better received if it asked What makes MSVC accept this code? (assuming the proper compiler flags are added).

@Erel "What makes MSVC accept this code?" A bug.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Well, possibly, or perhaps even most likely, but you know, MSVC has a lot of... Surprising extensions. Like this one. I wouldn't be (too) surprised if the reason were to be some obscure extension which has some side effect(s) in specific circumstances (such as very specific compiler flags, that aren't specified here)...

@Erel I tried MSVC. It accepts this definition with no specific compiler flags, and then you cannot use default as an expression (viewState x  = default; is an error). That's a bug in my book even if for some unfathomable reason it's intended to behave this way.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, Fair Point, I reworded the question.  I also looked at cppreference about enums and it didn't say that there were any restrictions on names that I could fine, hence my question.

@n.m.couldbeanAI - does it work with viewState x = viewState::default;?  With C++11, I don't think you can do using enum viewState

Dupe: Can a function be named default?

Ah sorry my bad, it accepts viewState::default as a name, and also a plain default if you use a plain old-style enum. That's crazy...

Keyword is a keyword in all contexts.
There are identifiers such as final or override that have special meaning only in some context, but they are not considered keywords in C++.
Maybe default could have been such an identifier with special meaning, rather than a keyword. But it isn't.
The purpose of making override not-a-keyword is avoiding breaking some code that uses override as an identifier. For default, which existed from the beginning, there isn't such a consideration.
